# How to best use SQL to find common IDs that match multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: sql

So I'm just starting to learn SQL, and hit upon the following problem.  Suppose I have a table with 3 columns like so:

```
ID    | Property_Name    | Property_Value
1     | Color            | "Blue"
1     | Size             | "Large"
2     | Color            | "Red"
3     | Color            | "Orange"
3     | Size             | "Small"
4     | Color            | "Blue"
4     | Size             | "Large"
...
```

Now, suppose I want to find the IDs that have Color=Blue and Size=Large (aka. ID 1 and 4),
how would I best do this.  The best way I came up with is the following, but it seems clunky...

```
SELECT ID FROM PropertyTable
WHERE
ID IN (
        SELECT ID FROM PropertyTable WHERE
        Property_Name='Color' AND Property_Value='blue' )
AND
(Property_Name='Size' AND Property_Value='Large')
```

Thank you :)

EDIT: Forgot to add preformat tags to the example table text. Just did so.

Comment: This is an odd construction.  Curious, why aren't "Size" and "Color" just columns on the data table?

Comment: That looks like exactly what I would have done, starting from your staring point. I'd bee considering whether combining different properties in one table will serve if the project scales up significantly. It might be better to separate `Size` from `Colour`, with different tables.

Comment: What DBMS are u using? SQL Server?

Comment: Poor table design in my opinion. Color and size should be columns on a single table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no authority over the database design. I am using DbVisualizer right now to run the SQL queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about self join?

```
SELECT T1.ID
FROM PropertyTable T1
JOIN PropertyTable T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE
        T1.PropertyName = 'Color' AND T1.PropertyValue = 'Blue'
    AND
        T2.PropertyName = 'Size' AND T2.PropertyValue = 'Large'
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d33f/1)

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer.  @goparkyourcar: Still, as my earlier comment hints at, I suspect this isn't the best way to store and search your data.  There is a fair chance that a lot of these "properties" could/should just be columns on your data table.

Comment: Looks like this solution works. Both this one and my original query took roughly the same time to execute on a table w/ 3500 rows. However, this one looks to be much easier to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the values for Color and Size don't overlap, then you can do something like this.

```
SELECT
 ID
FROM PropertyTable
WHERE Property_Name IN ('Color','Size') 
 AND Property_Value IN ('Blue','Large')
GROUP BY
 ID
HAVING 
 COUNT(ID) = 2
```

If they do overlap then try this.

```
SELECT
 ID
FROM PropertyTable
WHERE (Property_Name = 'Color' AND Property_Value = 'Blue')
 OR (Property_Name = 'Size' AND Property_Value = 'Large')
GROUP BY
 ID
HAVING 
 COUNT(ID) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  I think the most general approach is to use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select ID
from PropertyTable pt
group by ID
having sum(case when Property_Name='Color' AND Property_Value='blue' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when Property_Name='Size' AND Property_Value='Large' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each clause of the `having` statement is counting the number of rows that match each condition.

The reason I like this is because it is quite general  If you wanted to add in another property, you just add similar clauses:

```
select ID
from PropertyTable pt
group by ID
having sum(case when Property_Name='Color' AND Property_Value='blue' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when Property_Name='Size' AND Property_Value='Large' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when Property_Name = 'Heating' and Property_Value = 'Gas' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you wanted any of the three conditions, then you would use `or`:

```
select ID
from PropertyTable pt
group by ID
having sum(case when Property_Name='Color' AND Property_Value='blue' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when Property_Name='Size' AND Property_Value='Large' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when Property_Name = 'Heating' and Property_Value = 'Gas' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```